# nodejs use socket to receive a data.but it was split

Tags: node.js, sockets

[image]

I use data event to receive the data.look this log. this data was split 
to a few. so that i can't JSON.pare the data

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Please, see ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for details and edit your post accordingly!